# Rename using suggested var name with resharper

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, coding-style, resharper

I'm Using resharper 6 nighty builds and VB.net. I've a big medium project with multiple files that don't follow the code style conventions of my company.

I've configured resharper with my own convenctions and It suggest to me the right name for each variable (perfect!).

But I can't find any automagic way to make the current name to be replaced with the suggested name.

Are there any way to do it? If not ... did you know ane fearure of coderush Xpress to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've configured ReSharper with your naming conventions, then it should show a warning (blue squiggly underline) under any identifiers that don't comply. If you put the text cursor on one of those misnamed identifiers, you should see a pyramid icon appear near the left margin. Then you can press Alt+Enter (or click the pyramid icon) to drop down a quick-fix menu. There should be an option in the menu to "Rename to '_myField'". Usually it's the first item in the list, so you can just press Enter again to do the rename.

If you want to do this on everything in a source file, you can use the ReSharper > Inspect > Next Issue in File command (or its keyboard shortcut -- F12 in the IDEA keymap) to move the cursor to the next warning in the file. Then, if it's another name warning, you can use Alt+Enter, Enter again to fix it.

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to automatically fix every instance of a warning at once (though it's been requested; please feel free to vote for [RSRP-126551](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-126551) in their issue tracker).

Comment: Of course, this is the spected behaviour, and I just check that It works perfect in C#, but not in VB.net.

Comment: You're refusing to say which *part* doesn't work, which makes it hard for anyone to help. And do you know whether it worked in 5.1? It's always possible that something is broken in the 6.0 EAP builds. (Actually, a great many things are broken in the 6.0 EAP builds.)

Comment: I've asked directly to JetBrains. The naming conventions are not supported in 5.1 (no highlighting), They are supported in 6 (the highlight appears), but the automatic rename refactoring are limited only to fields. Don't work with local vars or params in functions. I've been in c# for a long time, and I didn't know that the features of resharper in vb are not the same.